# raw socket & security - Linux & Windows

Tags: linux, windows, networking

Do all versions of linux permit traffic over raw sockets ?

It seems that in Windows, the releases after Windows XP 
with SP2 have the ability to send traffic over 
raw sockets but has been restricted in two ways:

1. TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets.
2. UDP datagrams with invalid source addresses 
   cannot be sent over raw sockets. The IP source 
   address for any outgoing UDP datagram must exist 
   on a network interface or the datagram is dropped.

Are there any similar security measures in Linux ?
Any ideas ?

Thx in advans,
Karthik Balaguru

Answer (score 3):

Those are security measures that are annoyances for most.  Linux (and NetBSD) is open source, you can just make the kernel do what you want anyway.

The real security is root or not root.  This is sane, and the way it should be.

Comment: Compared to the restrictions incorporated by windows, doesn't this look less secure in linux ?

Comment: Less secure for whom?  You must be superuser to send these packets.  The reason Windows can put these restrictions in place is because you cannot just hack the kernel to get around them.  Also, malware which wants to spoof packets has a target in windows.  That is, Windows is so insecure already, this was an easy target to aim for.  Is it less secure that linux allows any header?  If you look at it right, I suppose, but in reality no.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real security benefit to the restrictions Windows imposes. To actually use raw sockets, you need to be superuser under both Windows and *nix; since you're the superuser, you could simply install your own stub protocol driver on Windows and send whatever packets you feel like. Alternatively, you could patch `tcpip.sys` (or whatever the appropriate file is) to remove the restrictions, as has been done for the half-open connection limitation. It's more work than simply sending on a SOCK_RAW socket, but it only has to be done once.

All the Windows restrictions do is prevent buggy, and not actively malicious software from causing a problem, break some malware that was current at the time the restrictions were introduced (anything more recent can simply work around the restrictions), and annoy any network administrator or software developer who needs to inject some packets for test purposes.